# How can I adapt AsyncLocalStorage to work with Symbol.dispose, to have an API like Python’s ContextVar?

Tags: node.js, typescript, task-local-storage, lexical-cleanup

I am trying to use Node's `AsyncLocalStorage` API and the newly introduced `using` keyword in Typescript 5.2 to simulate python's `ContextVar` behavior for logging.

The following python code works perfectly as I expected:

```python
# Output
# ------
# push {'fn': 'main', 'main': True}
# info {'msg': 'main: before', 'fn': 'main', 'main': True}
# push {'fn': 'a', 'a': True}
# push {'fn': 'b', 'b': True}
# info {'msg': 'a', 'fn': 'a', 'main': True, 'a': True}
# pop {'fn': 'a', 'a': True}
# info {'msg': 'b', 'fn': 'b', 'main': True, 'b': True}
# pop {'fn': 'b', 'b': True}
# info {'msg': 'main: after', 'fn': 'main', 'main': True}
# pop {'fn': 'main', 'main': True}

from contextvars import ContextVar
from contextlib import contextmanager
import asyncio


class Logger:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.store: ContextVar[list] = ContextVar("store", default=[])

    @contextmanager
    def with_meta(self, meta):
        try:
            stack = self.store.get()
            print("push", meta)
            self.store.set([*stack, meta])
            yield
        finally:
            stack = self.store.get()
            print("pop", stack.pop())

    @property
    def meta(self):
        stack = self.store.get()
        return {k: v for d in stack for k, v in d.items()}

    def info(self, msg):
        print("info", {**{"msg": msg}, **self.meta})


logger = Logger()


async def a():
    with logger.with_meta({"fn": "a", "a": True}):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        logger.info("a")


async def b():
    with logger.with_meta({"fn": "b", "b": True}):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        logger.info("b")


async def main():
    with logger.with_meta({"fn": "main", "main": True}):
        logger.info("main: before")
        await asyncio.gather(a(), b())
        logger.info("main: after")


asyncio.run(main())
```

However, when I convert it to typescript the props get all messed up:

```js
// Output:
// ------
// push { fn: 'main', main: true }
// info { msg: 'main: before', fn: 'main', main: true }
// push { fn: 'a', a: true }
// push { fn: 'b', b: true }
// info { msg: 'a', fn: 'b', main: true, a: true, b: true }
// pop { fn: 'b', b: true }
// info { msg: 'b', fn: 'a', main: true, a: true }
// pop { fn: 'a', a: true }
// info { msg: 'main: after', fn: 'main', main: true }
// pop { fn: 'main', main: true }

import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'node:async_hooks'

function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}


class Logger {
  private als: AsyncLocalStorage<any[]>
  constructor() {
    this.als = new AsyncLocalStorage()
    this.als.enterWith([])
  }

  withMeta(meta: any,) {
    const stack = this.als.getStore()!
    stack.push(meta)
    console.log('push', meta)
    return this
  }

  [Symbol.dispose]() {
    const stack = this.als.getStore()!
    console.log('pop', stack.pop())
  }

  get meta() {
    const stack = this.als.getStore()!
    return stack.reduce((prev, curr) => ({ ...prev, ...curr }), {})
  }

  info(msg: string) {
    console.log('info', { msg, ...this.meta })
  }
}

const logger = new Logger()

async function a() {
  using _ = logger.withMeta({ fn: 'a', a: true })
  await sleep(200)
  logger.info('a')
}

async function b() {
  using _ = logger.withMeta({ fn: 'b', b: true })
  await sleep(200)
  logger.info('b')
}

async function main() {
  using _ = logger.withMeta({ fn: 'main', main: true })
  logger.info('main: before')
  await Promise.all([a(), b()])
  logger.info('main: after')
}

main().catch(console.error)
```

For instance the context of `a` gets mixed with the context of `b`

What does `ContextVar` do differently from `AsyncLocalStorage`? It seems like `AsyncLocalStorage` is using the same store no matter what, while ContextVar seems to "fork/copy" when new Tasks/Promises get created.

Is there a way to achieve the python behavior in node?

Comment: They should serve the same purpose, AsyncLocalStorage is context local to promise chains. And ContextVar is context local to async operations in python. Both serve as something similar to thread local storage.